# Generic method to insert record into DB

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Entity Frame work as an ORM and i want to have a single generic method for inserting different entities. say for example i have two entities `foo` and `bar` and i am currently adding them like

```
internal void Add(Foo _foo){ dbContext.Foo.AddObject(_foo); }
```

and for `bar`

```
internal void Add(Bar _bar){ dbContext.Bar.AddObject(_bar); }
```

i am finding it difficult to wrap my head around the generics. Please help me in writing a generic method for inserting typeOf entities. Plus if somebody guide me to a beginner level tutorial i'll greatful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
internal void Add<T>(T entity) { dbcontext.Set<T>.Add(entity); }
```

Then you call it like so:

```
obj.Add(foo);
```

The type is inferred, so you don't have to specify it directly.  Set is a method that uses generics to retrieve the DbSet based on type, rather than having to specify the set name.